# Order dataframe by two values and assign category per n-size

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe with two columns:

```
data = [ 
  (0, 'A'), 
  (0, 'B'), 
  (0, 'C'), 
  (1, 'D'), 
  (1, 'E'), 
  (2, 'F'), 
  (3, 'G'), 
  (4, 'H'), 
  (5, 'I'),
] 

schm = ['val', 'id'] 

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=schm) 
df.show()

+---+---+
|val| id|
+---+---+
|  0|  A|
|  0|  B|
|  0|  C|
|  1|  D|
|  1|  E|
|  2|  F|
|  3|  G|
|  4|  H|
|  5|  I|
+---+---+
```

Notice, the `id` values are unique but the `val` values are not. I've seen solutions grouping by the `val` but that won't work in this case.

The sample is already in order, but say I order them by `val` then `id` and store that in a row number (`rn`) column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number,lit
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window().orderBy('val', 'id')
df = df.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(w))
df.show()

+---+---+---+
|val| id| rn|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  A|  1|
|  0|  B|  2|
|  0|  C|  3|
|  1|  D|  4|
|  1|  E|  5|
|  2|  F|  6|
|  3|  G|  7|
|  4|  H|  8|
|  5|  I|  9|
+---+---+---+
```

I want to add a new column to categorize them into four buckets of equal n-size.

```
n_splits = 4
  
# Calculate count of each dataframe rows 
each_len = df.count() // n_splits 

each_len
2
```

I kind of get there doing something like this:

```
b1 = range(0, each_len)
b2 = range(b1[-1], each_len*2)
b3 = range(b2[-1], each_len*3)
b4 = range(b3[-1], each_len*4)

df = df.withColumn('cat', when(col('rn').between(b1[1], b1[-1]), 1)
                                                .when(col('rn').between(b2[1], b2[-1]), 2)
                                                .when(col('rn').between(b3[1], b3[-1]), 3)
                                                .when(col('rn').between(b4[1], b4[-1]), 4))

df.show()

+---+---+---+----+
|val| id| rn| cat|
+---+---+---+----+
|  0|  A|  1|   1|
|  0|  B|  2|   2|
|  0|  C|  3|   2|
|  1|  D|  4|   3|
|  1|  E|  5|   3|
|  2|  F|  6|   4|
|  3|  G|  7|   4|
|  4|  H|  8|null|
|  5|  I|  9|null|
+---+---+---+----+
```

However, there must be a more elegant and programmatic way. I figure the `null`s can be assigned the last category (`4`) as well.

I want output like:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|val| id| rn|cat|
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  A|  1|  1|
|  0|  B|  2|  1|
|  0|  C|  3|  2|
|  1|  D|  4|  2|
|  1|  E|  5|  3|
|  2|  F|  6|  3|
|  3|  G|  7|  4|
|  4|  H|  8|  4|
|  5|  I|  9|  4|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: What happens if `n_splits>=5`? How would you assign categories considering you only have 9 rows?

Comment: In this case I know I need only 4. However, if 5 then the `each_len` would be 1, and the four remaining rows would get assigned the final category value (`5`).